# How can I use GoReleaser to sign a binary with a GPG key that requires a passphrase

Tags: terraform, gpg-signature, hashicorp, goreleaser

So it looks like Terraform recommends this [config](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-scaffolding/blob/main/.goreleaser.yml) for GoReleaser, when I looked at it, there's nothing that uses `sign` parameter or something, does it mean that every project that uses this GoReleaser config uses an open GPG key then?

> GoReleaser does not support signing binaries with a GPG key that requires a passphrase.

source: https://www.terraform.io/docs/registry/providers/publishing.html

Answer (score 1):

You can probably provide the password using the `stdin` property, e.g.:

```yaml
signs:
  - artifacts: checksum
    args:
      - "--batch"
      - "--local-user"
      - "{{ .Env.GPG_FINGERPRINT }}"
      - "--output"
      - "${signature}"
      - "--detach-sign"
      - "${artifact}"
    stdin: '{{ .Env.GPG_PASSWORD }}'
```